# Angular: data binding to data attributes does not work

Tags: angular, data-binding

I have following code where I add data attribute `data-description`

```
<span *ngFor="let item of images">

<img
        src="{{ item.url }}"
        alt="{{ item.name }}"
        data-description="{{ item.description }}"
      />
</span>
```

The generated html code is

```
<span>    
    <img
            src="url/here"
            alt="name/here"
          />
    </span>
```

As you can see `data-description` does not show at all. How can I add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind to `attr` property as the `data-` specification depends specifically on HTML attributes rather than properties of DOM elements.

In your case you can have

```html
<span *ngFor="let item of images">
    <img
        [src]="item.url"
        [alt.alt]="item.name"
        [attr.data-description]="item.description"
      />
</span>
```

Below is a sample output [See this Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-k7es59)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of string interpolation, use binding, to bind to `data-description`, Use `attr` prefix.

```html
[attr.data-description]="item.description"
```

I will change the `src` interpolation to a prop binding as well:

```html
<span *ngFor="let item of images">
    <img
        [src]="item.url"
        [alt]="item.name"
        [attr.data-description]="item.description"
      />
</span>
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-64666561?file=src/app/app.component.html)